# Host And Expose Application to local small network

Tags: web-hosting

I developed a little application (web application) using JavaEE+MySql. I try to keep some data and .. from time to time to get some reports using my data.

My problem is I have to access this application from 4-5 computers in the office. They are connected through a switch. It's a typical small office network, nothing fancy.

I need some advice on how to do this. I mean for a small application with no external communication is it mandatory to use an Apache machine?

I'd use a simple Tomcat container on the "server machine" (which is my computer, a windows machine) and .. basically .. I would like to permit the access to my colleagues also.

I don't have any knowledge about concurrency (I know mysql permits concurrent access) so I would like some configuration tips also.

Answer (score 1):

**Apache makes a fine choice for local networking for web & Java Applets**

[Apache](http://www.apache.org/) is absolutely fine for local hosting onto a internal network, in fact its actually very simple and you should find almost everything out of the box works for you since you shouldn't need to open any ports since normally by default these are open for local networks. In regards of MySQL its a lot easier to install [phpmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) and adjust the user accounts via a dashboard or alternatively install something like [webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) which can help install and setup other server applications.

**Tomcat Apache**

Also you could always [install Tomcat onto of Apache](http://tomcat.apache.org/) should you want to keep it all Linux based which in my honest opinion tends to be easier to manage but some people prefer windows so its down to preference I guess.

**Other stacks can assist**

If you get stuck at any point try [server fault](https://serverfault.com/), [unix and linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or if you install ubuntu try [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), the guys on these stacks are really helpful and should be able to help you with any problems you run into.